# Still getting double redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

This is what I got on htaccess for my client yogalaurent.com:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I am checking redirections with this tool:
https://varvy.com/tools/redirects/

It tells me there is still a double redirection:
http://yogalaurentretreats.com 301 redirect > http://www.yogalaurentretreats.com/ then http://www.yogalaurentretreats.com/ 301 redirect> https://www.yogalaurentretreats.com/

This is a WordPress site, I have checked plugins in case we can blame any of them, and I found nothing.

Can anyone help to find where that double redirection is coming from?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you enable rewrite logging to be able to follow on a step by step base what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine. The documentation explains how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recommended [this](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) .htaccess testing tool by one of the lead developers at my firm, and running your code through this test, with the test URL http://yogalaurentretreats.com returns the expected result (1 redirect to https://www.), so this would suggest that the first redirect (to http://www) is, in fact, being triggered before your code within the .htaccess.

This may be an option either within the hosting panel (for example, Plesk has a "preferred domain" setting), or within Wordpress, depending on the "siteurl" and "home" variables, configurable at "Settings" -> "General" in the Wordpress panel.

As [@arkascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248114/arkascha) suggests, rewrite logging would be invaluable, provided neither of the above are solutions to your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much and also @arkascha . I am now speaking about this with my hosting company as they have been telling me that all is set up correctly on their site.  I will keep you posted.  Thank you for sharing the htaccess testing tool with me.  Really appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved now.  This is what support at my hosting company said: "We have adjusted the Cloudflare redirect to redirect straight to HTTPS." It looks like the issue was there.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to hear it's sorted. Be sure to accept an answer so your question is flagged as resolved!